# Spring MVC + bootstrap-select multiple

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

How can I use Spring MVC 3.2.3 with bootstrap selectpicker properly?

I create selectpicker in JSP:

```
<form:form role="form" id="orgForm" commandName="orgDto" >
...
<form:select id="affOrgId" class="form-control selectpicker" path="affOrgIds" itemValue="id" multiple="true" items="${organizations}" itemLabel="label"/>
```

and activate it in js:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

Here is my form handler method header in controller class:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody
OrganizationDto updateOrganization(@PathVariable Long id,@Valid @RequestBody OrganizationDto org) {
```

I tryed to bind selectpicker selected values to `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` in model class (OrganizationDto):

```
private List<String> affOrgIds;
```

When I select a few values in selectpicker and submit a form I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@5c82a3e5; line: 1, column: 205] (through reference chain: com.org.OrganizationDto["affOrgIds"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
```

And in chrome developer tools in JSON Request Payload there is only one value:

```
    affOrgIds:"48"
```

(Also there is some strange field in json: _affOrgIds:"1". What's that?)

I create this json in JS this way:

```
var dataObj = $form.serializeJSON();
```

and then create PUT request by `$.ajax()`  method.
When I debug it there is `affOrgIds:"48"` in `dataObj`

So how to bind Spring MVC with bootstrap selectpicker to submit multiple selected values?

**UPD:** I suspect serializeJSON() work not correctly in this situation and I have to create JSON in other way.

**RESOLVED:** added `dataObj.affOrgIds = $form.find('#affOrgId').val();`

Comment: I don't understand where this `JSON` coming from. do you use `@RestController`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to write it... Updated...

Comment: You should either answer your own question or close this question if it is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$form.serializeJSON() works not correct for bootstrap-selectpicker.
To get selectpicker values I use  $form.find('#affOrgId').val();